# Iteratively and recursively find if there is an element in vector

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

I have a homework, working with vectors in C++. I have to implement intersection and difference of two vectors, and all that recursively.

First I create iteratively version which is working just fine:

```
bool mfind(int x, vector<int> array) {
    if (array.size() != 0) {
        while (array.size() != 0) {
            if (array.back() == x) {
                return true;
            } else {
                array.pop_back();
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        cout << "array is empty" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to do  recursively:

```
bool mfind(int x, vector<int> array) {
    if (array.size() != 0) {
        if (array.back() == x) {
            cout << "array.back == a" << endl;
            return true;
        } else {
            cout << "array.back = " << array.back() << endl;
            array.pop_back();
            mfind(x, array);
        }
    } else {
        cout << "array is empty" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, because if I save the function result in some bool var, the result is both, true and false!

Comment: Out of the question scope, but maybe this isn't what the homework expects. There are quicker alternatives to find intersection or difference of arrays.

Comment: Yes the scope is exactly right. I have to re implement all those functions which vector already have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is a return statement in the recursive call:

```
cout << "array.back = " << array.back() << endl;
array.pop_back();
return mfind(x, array);
```

Basically what you want to do is:

- If the array is empty, return `false`, the searched element isn't there.
- If the last element is the searched element, return `true`, the searched element is there.
- If the last element isn't the searched element, **return**, whether the element is in the rest of the list.

Comment: OMG! That is right. How can I miss something like that. Thank You very much